# Directory name invalid in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have created a new project in R Studio and I want to use Github to share and collaborate with others.

So I have this Github repository with the same name of the project and I'm trying to keep the files synch.

However, in R Studio, when trying to commit the changes I'm making, I get this strange error: "Directory name invalid":

[image: R]

I have found other similar questions here in Stack overflow, but they didn't help. The directory name is "Algortimos"

Comment: Maybe a typo? "Algortimos" or "Algoritmos"? ("t" and "i" are swapped.)

Comment: Lol, that's not the case, thanks!

Comment: Are any of the letters in your directory name accented?  In the error message, the "ó" in "diretório" and the "á" in "inválido" (plus one other, but I can't guess what that is) aren't being displayed properly.  That makes it look as though your system doesn't like Portuguese.

Comment: The directory name isn't accented. Only the path to that directory is.